# Problem with Attribute Assistant Expression Command

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, coding-style, attribute-assistant

I am using the Attribute Assistant add-in to perform multiple steps when a new feature is created. Two of the important steps are: generate a unique, incremental ID (project ID) and then use that project ID to build a larger docket number.

I have gotten the generate ID field to work properly and create a number in a field called PROJECTID. I then also have a field called COMPLAINT which tracks the type of complaint. The expression I want to build is [COMPLAINT] & "-2016-" & [PROJECTID], so the docket number will look something like VTW-2016-1.

I can get the the expression to work when I just use [COMPLAINT] & "-2016-", but when I add on the [PROJECTID] to the end of the expression, the tool fails and the field remains Null.

I will attach two images below, one of my DynamicValue table and one of the log that is tracking the error. [image: Error Message Log][image: DynamicValue Table]

We are using ArcGIS 10.2.2 in an SDE database on SQL server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DynamicValue table your expression is `[COMPLAINT] + "-2016-" + [PROJECTID]` but in the text of your qestion you say that it's `[COMPLAINT] & "-2016-" & [PROJECTID]` with `+` instead of `&`.

I believe the expressions use VBScript so the expression `[COMPLAINT] & "-2016-" & [PROJECTID]` looks more correct to me.  You are getting a `Type mismatch` error in your log as it's trying to add (because of the `+`) the PROJECTID number to the string `"VTW-2016-"`.  Try changing the `+` to `&`.

```
[COMPLAINT] & "-2016-" & [PROJECTID]
```

If that still doesn't work it may require your PROJECTID number to be converted to a string before concatenating it with the rest of the string.

Also in this situation I would set a Rule Weight just to be sure the rule for generating the PROJECTID runs before the expression for UNIQUEID:

> Rank rules in order of priority. Rules with a higher weight are
>   processed first. Rules with null values are always run last.

Comment: I have gotten the expression to work with a new projectID field that is text instead of integer. So the problem was related to the field type. However, I cannot get the process to work upon the creation of the record. I have to set up the generate project ID to occur "on create" and then the build docket expression to occur "on manual". Any thoughts on how to make both work with "on create"? I even tried setting them both up for "On create" with a rule weight of 1 and 2 but that didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @JacobDA I have set up a scenario the same as yours - an ID field (integer) and a text field for complaint, and another text field to contain the concatenated value. The ID field is generated using GENERATE_ID, and the concatenated value is auto-populated on create using the ID generated at the same time.  There might be something else going wrong here for you.

Comment: @JacobDA I'm interested to know if you got this working?  Happy to help get it going (which from my experience it should work)

Comment: I did get this to work by setting the concatenating step to occur  "on change (attribute)". This is the better option for me anyway because it will update the docket in the event that the complaint type changes. Although now I am having another problem which may require a new question. I can't seem to get data to copy from one table to a related table using attribute assistant. I will likely post a new question with more details if I cannot get it figured out today.

Comment: @JacobDA good to hear you got it going.  I'll keep an eye out for another question